# How to check a android app is running on mobile android device or desktop android device(Android-x86 OS)?

Tags: android, android-x86

I am working on a project where I need to know app is running on android mobile device or android desktop device.
I have installed Android-x86 OS on my PC and I am making app for Android-x86. How to know our code is running on android mobile device or android desktop device?

Comment: Do you mean real device or emulator ?

Comment: real device, I have install Android OS on my PC

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public boolean isGenymotionEmulatorDevice(String manufacturer) {
   return manufacturer.toUpperCase().contains("GENYMOTION");
}

 public boolean isGoogleEmulatorDevice(String model) {
    String modelUpper = model.toUpperCase();
    return modelUpper.contains("GOOGLE_SDK")
           || modelUpper.contains("SDK")
           || modelUpper.contains("EMULATOR");
}
```

Usage

```
boolean isGenymotionEmulator = isGenymotionEmulatorDevice(Build.MANUFACTURER)
boolean isGoogleEmulator = isGoogleEmulatorDevice(Build.MODEL)
```

Comment: Hi @sergeyBukarev, I am not talking about emulator. I install android Android-x86 OS on my PC, So how i configuration of Android mobile OS differentiate from  Android desktop OS?

Comment: OK. Are there any special notes in the Build.MODEL or Build.MANUFACTURER variable?

Comment: Please google for  Android-x86 OS. Then you can understand my question easily.